# I made a queue management system and created a function to add two queues

Tags: c++, pointers, queue, operator-overloading

Here's my code. I created the function to add two  queues using the operation overloading. For some reson it always returns an empty

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

class Queue { 
    int size; 
    int* queue; 
    
    public:
    Queue() { 
        size = 0;
        queue = new int[100];
    }
    //adds an item to  the queue`enter code here`
    void add(int data) { 
        queue[size] = data; 
        size++;
    }
    //removes an item from the queue
    void remove() { 
        if (size == 0) { 
            cout << "Queue is empty"<<endl; 
            return; 
        } 
        else { 
            for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) { 
                queue[i] = queue[i + 1]; 
            } 
            size--; 
        } 
    } 
    // a function to display the queue
    void print() { 
        if (size == 0) { 
            cout << "Queue is empty"<<endl; 
            return; 
        } 
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
            cout<<queue[i]<<" <- ";
        } 
        cout << endl;
    }
```

This is the function to add the queues. It is not returning an error. But whenever I tried to add the queues it always return an empty queue. What could be the problem

```
  Queue operator+(Queue &obj){
      Queue res;
      res.queue = *queue + obj.queue;
      return res;
  }
    
};
```

Here starts the main function.

```
 int main() { 
    Queue q1; 
    q1.add(42); q1.add(2); q1.add(8);  q1.add(1);
    Queue q2;
    q2.add(3); q2.add(66); q2.add(128);  q2.add(5);
    Queue q3 = q1+q2;
    q3.print();

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `*queue + obj.queue` This doesn't concatenate two integer arrays, as you appear to believe. This takes a pointer `obj.queue`, increments it by the integer `*queue` (apparently, the first element in the queue), and returns the resulting pointer. Basically, it doesn't make sense - you just randomly stumbled on a non-sensical expression that just happens to compile.

Comment: Your understanding of how pointers and memory allocations work is fundamentally incorrect. The shown code needs to be fundamentally rewritten in multiple ways. That's ok, everyone has to learn this at some point, however the best way to learn this is by continuing to read and study your textbook, and try its practice programs. Stackoverflow is not a replacement for your textbook, unfortunately.

Comment: oh, Thanks... I am newbie and I've just started learning about pointers and memory allocations. May be I need to  learn more about this topic

Comment: Sir can you please tell me how can I add the the two queues using operator overloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should do something like this. This code isn't going to win any prizes for style, I'm just trying to show you what is required

```
Queue operator+(Queue &obj){
  Queue res;
  res.size = size + obj.size; // work out the new queues size
  res.queue = new int[100]; // allocate memory for new queue
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) // copy from first queue to new queue
      res.queue[i] = queue[i];
  for (int i = 0; i < obj.size; ++i) // copy from second queue to new queue
      res.queue[size + i] = obj.queue[i];
  return res;
}
```

As I said there are all sorts of things wrong with this code, and with the other code you have written. But it will hopefully give you some idea of what you need to do.

Comment: It did worked !! I just replaced queue[i]; to obj.queue[i] in the 8th line of the code you just posted. That made so much sense. I was just incrementing upon the same pointer. Thank you so much sir

Comment: @SandeshYadav Yes, that was a mistake, well spotted. I've fixed it myself as well.